# Как правильно вставит переменную в цикле?

Tags: javascript

Как правильно записать в переменную в цикле for вот такого вида

```
       var playlist = [
         {
          author:"",
          title:audio[i].trackname,
          discription: "",
          mp3:'https://site.ru/music/'+audio[i].url,
          oga:""
         },
 ];
```

в переменную playlist надо вставлять из цикла:

```
{
 author:"",
 title:audio[i].trackname,
 discription: "",
 mp3:'https://site.ru/music/'+audio[i].url,
 oga:""
 },

var i;
for(i=0;i<audio.length;i++) {
console.log(audio[i]);
}
```

Как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
playlist = []

for (let i = 0; i < audio.length; i++) {
​
 playlist[i] = {
 author:"",
 title:audio[i].trackname,
 discription: "",
 mp3:'https://site.ru/music/'+audio[i].url,
 oga:""
}
​
}
```

Comment: Спасибо.Помогло

Answer (score 1):

```
  const playlist = audio.map(track => ({
  author: '',
  title: track.trackname,
  description: '',
  mp3: `https://site.ru/music/${track.url}`,
  oga: ''
}));
```